# Data from Firestore isn´t showing up in listview

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data on Firestore:
[image]

I am using this code to get ’name’ from every document to show up in a listview:

```
Widget buildUserList(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];

            return ListTile(
                // Access the fields as defined in FireStore
                title: Text(user.data['name']),
            );
        },
    );
} else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && !snapshot.hasData) {
    // Handle no data
    return Center(
        child: Text("No users found."),
    );
} else {
    // Still loading
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
}
```

And to show it in body:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream:
        Firestore.instance.collection('markers').snapshots(),
    builder: buildUserList,
)
```

The problem is that the listview is empty. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there an error being displayed in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so there are two errors that I was getting when I ran your code. The first one was that the ListView needs to have a bounded height which can be easily done with the container or sized box widgets. The fixed sample of code below will have a container to bound the height. Another issue was that the ListTile widget needs to have a Material widget in the widget tree and you might already have a material widget in your widget tree somewhere that just was no included in your question but if not the sample of code below will also address that issue as well. Hopefully that helps! Comment if you have any questions!

```
Widget buildUserList(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container(
          height: 350,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];

                  return Material(
                    child: ListTile(
                        // Access the fields as defined in FireStore
                        title: Text(user.data['first name']),
                    ),
                  );
              },
          ),
        );
    } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && !snapshot.hasData) {
        // Handle no data
        return Center(
            child: Text("No users found."),
        );
    } else {
        // Still loading
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
```